# How to write a VIM color scheme?

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

I have been looking around for VIM color schemes and found some great ones out there (esp. by using http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/), but I always want to change a few aspects of each one I find. So I've decided now that what I really want to do is make my own, or be able to customize the ones I find on the fly. Basically, what I want to know is:

1) How do I write a vim color scheme -- are there any good (quick) tutorials?

2) How do I add language-specific customizations? Like say for Python, I might be interested in having different colors for classes and methods (is this even possible? What level of customization is possible?). Anything you can tell me about how to customize for specific languages would be fantastic! (esp. python, but also others like C, Java, Ruby would be great)

3) Are there are good, **complete** (ideally well-commented) templates that I could start from which contain all aspects of a color scheme, like background, text, language specific stuff, and the like?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I didn't watch the ["Creating colorschemes for Vim"](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/) episode of [VIMcasts](http://vimcasts.org/), but the others are really good.

Answer (score 46):

[Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/) lets you interactively create vim colorschemes with color pickers and previews your scheme using several code samples.

Comment: @desimusxvii How do I change python-builtin function colors?

Comment: I literally thought of writing something like this today! Glad I didn't do it lol

Answer (score 14):

colorschemes are actually vim scripts. You use the hi command for coloring, which works like 
`hi TextType guifg=#hexforegroundcolor guibg=#hexbgcolor gui=bold/italic/underlined/undercurled` (assumed you use gvim). If you type `:hi`only, you get a complete list of text types with their current highlighting
see also http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:colorscheme

Answer (score 8):

May be you can find this colorscheme template useful: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=106

The original description is

"The philosophy here is to provide a ready-to-uncomment list of highlight commands for all the important groups.  Then you can deviate from the default until you come up with one you like."

Comment: very nice, that looks like exactly what I was looking for in a template when I asked the question!

Comment: I did a Colorscheme some time ago too. Now that SourceForge is off the grid, it can be used instead. https://github.com/Heldraug/Vim-Colorscheme-Template

Comment: this is great, excellent way to start understanding how to make a vim colorscheme

Answer (score 6):

Launch vim, say ":help syntax", it has quick start etc.

For the complete templates look at your installation:

colorschemes are in /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/colors/

languages syntax in /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/syntax/