# Error with colorscheme genereated by vivify

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I was searching for a guide on how to write a color scheme, when I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396647/how-to-write-a-vim-color-scheme). So I created a colorscheme for vim using [Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/), but when I try to use it an error occurs on the following line:

```
hi cterm=.((s:fontface==plain) ? none : bold) guifg=#efface guibg=#efface guisp=#efface gui=NONE ctermfg=230 ctermbg=230 cterm=NONE
```

and it is about a missing equal sign.

I add a link to the [.vim file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17093893/enrico.vim) as suggested by @Carolyn C.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `hi` is looking for a type of text to apply the colors to, as well as having trouble with the ternary operator. In addition,`s:fontface` seems to be an undefined variable. You could try try changing it to either `cterm=none` or `cterm=bold`.

could you link to the full file so I could see context for having a `hi` without a group name?

Comment: I added the link to the file. It is too be big, so I cannot add it to the question. But, if you find a soution to the problem, you can modify my question by adding only the part to modify.

Comment: Well, I can't for the life of me figure out what that line is supposed to do, I would comment it out, then load the colors and use `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim` to see if anything is glaringly missing